# Problem with logical operators precedence

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm studying logical operators for school and there's a weird question that keeps bugging me even though it seems pretty basic.

I was asked to evaluate the proposition : **p -> q -> r** with p, r are False and q is True.

I tried evaluating it from left to right like this: **( ( p -> q ) -> r )** and got wrong answer. 

Then, I checked my result with an online tool at https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/ and it evaluates the proposition from right to left like this:  **( p -> ( q -> r ) )** ( you can see in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5fnm.png) ). I tried calculating the result again with this order and it was accepted as right answer !

That's really odd because my lecturer said that if operators are at the same level then the proposition should be evaluated from left to right. Have I misunderstood something ?

Comment: It is a [convention](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/glossary/operator_precedence.html): **usually** "operators of equal precedence associates to the right."

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Is interpreting  p=>q=>r  as  (p=>q AND q=>r) also an accepted convention ? because I've seen it being used that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the operations $\wedge,\vee,\Leftrightarrow$ are left-associative while the operation $\Rightarrow$ is right-associative.
So

$[p\Rightarrow q\Rightarrow r ]\Longleftrightarrow [p\Rightarrow (q\Rightarrow r)].$

Comment: Thanks for your answer and  Mauro ALLEGRANZA' s comment too. It turns out I've really misunderstood this question .

Comment: I do not agree with the statement that $\land$ and $\lor$ are left-associative.

Comment: They are both left- and right-associative.

Comment: So, I checked everything again using https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool and it showed that ↔ is right associative. It's different from your answer !

Comment: This document: http://intrologic.stanford.edu/glossary/operator_precedence.html also confirms that ⟺ is right associative.

Comment: @CPS_001 - the issue is that the "symmetric" operators ($\land,\lor,\leftrightarrow$) are **associative**, both left- and right-. Thus, the simplest rule is: right-associativity for all binary connectives.

Answer (score 0):

The full convention is as follows: Outermost parentheses may be omitted, and in the absence of parentheses, the order of operations is

1. $\lnot$
2. $\land$
3. $\lor$
4. $\impliedby $ and $\implies$ have equal precedence
5. $\iff$

$\impliedby$ is left associative, and as Wuestenfux stated, $\implies$ is right associative while $\iff$ is left associative.

An example using everthing would be: $a\lor b\impliedby ~a\iff a\land\lnot a\lor b$, which reads $(a\lor b\impliedby (~a\iff ((a\land\lnot a)\lor b)))$.